# I can't position and center element like I want to

Tags: html, css, user-interface

---

I have got problems putting my own UI into frontend I have started putting navigation but things got really really wrong.
this what I have created in my UI.

---

[image: Website Image]

---

what I came with is this.

[image: my dumb design/frontend]

---

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* container */

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-items li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-items li h1 {
  display: inline;
}

.left-item {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.left-item a {
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 0 12px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  padding: 33px 0;
}

.blueBg {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
this my Html


<header class="blueBg">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- navgation bar -->
    <nav>
      <!-- Nav items -->
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li>
          <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
        </li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>blog</li>
        <li>products</li>
        <li>clients</li>
        <li>contact us</li>
        <li class="left-item"><a href="">get started</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I'm not Professional FrontEnd so Need little help to figure out what is wrong why my code doesn't look like my design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into `display: flex;`, there are several great articles about it. Wes Bos has a free video tutorial on it, but you will find a ton of good tutorials.

I just broke out the logo and get started out of the navigation ul. You need to correct the css for the elements. What makes this work is the following css

this makes the items in a row, justify-content places it all in the center.

```
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

The margin-right pushes the logo to the far left

```
.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

the margin-left pushes get started to the far right

```
.get-started {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* container */

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-items li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-items li h1 {
  display: block;
}

.get-started {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

nav {
  padding: 33px 0;
}

.blueBg {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header class="blueBg">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- navgation bar -->
    <nav class="navigation">
      <!-- Nav items -->
      <a href="/" class="logo">
        Logo
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-items">
        <li>home</li>
        <li>blog</li>
        <li>products</li>
        <li>clients</li>
        <li>contact us</li>
      </ul>
      
      <a href="" class="get-started">get started</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you need to divide your html body into rows and columns. For example, your top navbar is going to be first row while this text and search field and button should be in the second row.

As I see, you want to separate things in top navbar, so you have to divide first row into columns, as much as you need. In your case that's 3 columns. Than you can config parameters such as size, position, color and etc. for each column.

Or if you want to make minimum changes with your code, try something like this:

```
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a style="margin-left: 30px; text-align: left">
      <img src="path to logo" width="30" height="30">
    </a>
    <ul style="text-align: center;">
      <li>home</li>
      <li>blog</li>
      <li>products</li>
      <li>clients</li>
      <li>contact us</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="" class="get-started" style="text-align: right;">
      Get Started
    </a>
  <div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean. Please show some code because this is not all that helpful.

Comment: I strongly recommend Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) because it has so many CSS classes already written for you.

Comment: this is still not a valid answer.